# What did Buster Moon say to the dancers that offended them?

Tags: plot-explanation, sing

During the movie *Sing*, Buster Moon constantly tries to shoo away five young, presumably Asian dancers, but finally he attempts to allow them in his show. Finding they can't speak English, he gets out a translation dictionary and says something that seemed to offend them as one slapped Buster.

What was it that Buster said to them?

Comment: "you are very stinky" and then something about legs? sorry, can't be more of help!

Comment: Shouldn't the other question have been marked as a duplicate of this one as mine is 5 months older?

Answer (score 1):

He literally said あなただしすごくくさいよ= 'You guys suck.' So Buster meant to say they're good, but pronounced it wrong. Then he proceeds by saying 'Your footwork is bad' which offends the red pandas. What he meant to say was 'Sleep well for tomorrow' like he said to everyone else.

Comment: Do you have a source? Are you a translator?

Comment: I am the source and no.

Comment: What are the characters for "You are good, sleep well for tomorrow?"

Comment: Google Translate says あなただしすごくくさいよ means "It's you, it's awesome". Even if it's a little off, isn't this a complement rather than an offense?

Answer (score 0):

Buster tried to say, "You may be in my show", but instead, he said, "You have a horrible routine and did not make it", and I know this because I am a translator, but I did not find the words. Buster probably picked up the wrong book, or pronounced it wrong.

Comment: If you didn't find the words, how do you know that's what he said?